# AngularJS promise undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have read several examples on the web and issues here on SO but I'm still missing something.

I have a service to fetch order data from my API. I want to resolve the promise inside the service. The console.log inside the service logs the correct data.

However, in my controller i get ***"TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"***

I thought the controller function would wait for the data to be resolved?

**Service**

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('orderService', function($http) {

    // DECLARATIONS
    var baseUrl = 'http://api.example.com/';
    var method = 'GET';
    var orderData = null;

    return {
        getOrderData: getOrderData
    };

    // IMPLEMENTATIONS
    function getOrderData(ordernumber) {        
        // order data does not yet exist in service
        if(!orderData) {
            dataPromise = $http({
                url: baseUrl + 'order/' + ordernumber,
                method: method,
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            // success
            }).then(function(response) {
                orderData = response.data;
                console.log('Received data: ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
                return orderData;               
            },
            // faliure
            function(error) {
                  console.log("The request failed: " + error);
            });
        // order data exist in service
        } else {
            console.log('Data present in service: ' + orderData);
            return orderData;
        }
    } // end: getOrderData function
}); // end: customerService
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('orderController', function($scope, $stateParams, orderService) {

   $scope.ordernumber = $stateParams.order;

   orderService.getOrderData($scope.ordernumber)
    // success 
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.order = response;
        console.log('Controller response: ' + response);
    },
    // faliure
    function(error) {
      console.log("The request failed: " + error);
    });
});
```

Comment: So you're trying to cache the response of a request. But you cache only one result. What if the `ordernumber` changes, you'll still return the result for the old `ordernumber`. And how long is the result valid? You have no concept of invalidating the cached data in your code. The whole caching concept here broken; you should rethink it. Till then you can simplify your function to `function getOrderData(ordernumber) { return $http(...).then(response => response.data) }`. this doesn't cache but it returns correct results

Comment: yeah, that did cross my mind even before I posted the code. That the order number will change. Thanks for the input! I will ofc strip it, for now the amount of data transferred is so low I don't actually need it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your function `getOrderData` doesn return a promise

```
function getOrderData(ordernumber) {        
   var deferred = $q.defer();
        // order data does not yet exist in service
        if(!orderData) {
            dataPromise = $http({
                url: baseUrl + 'order/' + ordernumber,
                method: method,
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            // success
            }).then(function(response) {
                orderData = response.data;
                console.log('Received data: ' + 
                 JSON.stringify(response.data));
                deferred.resolve(orderData);               
            },
            // faliure
            function(error) {
              deferred.reject(error);
                  console.log("The request failed: " + error);
            });
        // order data exist in service
        } else {
            console.log('Data present in service: ' + orderData);
            deferred.resolve(orderData);
        }
    else {
     deferred.reject('Not set!');
   }

return deferred.promise;
    } // end: getOrderData function
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for your help. Am going to read through a bit on $q. The else statement for your deferred.reject is missing the opening if. I deleted the else just to try it out and everything worked. Do you mind editing your code? Thanks again!

Comment: I've put those `else` statement because if the condition in your `if` statement is somehow `false` the promise will be always open and you wouldn't get any error or success in your controller

Comment: **Avoid using the deferred antipattern.** And you can simplify the structure of your code to `function getOrderData(ordernumber) {
 if(!orderData) orderData = $http(...).then(response => response.data);
 return orderData;
}` but the whole caching-concept in this question *(not your code in particular)* is broken.

Comment: I know that is better just to return the `$http` the cause to do it with deferred promise is that he has some logic, before the call of `$http`

Comment: But the whole logic before the request can be covered as `if(!cachedPromise) cachedPromise = ...; return cachedPromise`. And `$http` provides you with a promise to cache. So you don't need to create any promise yourself for this.